# The size of data of an address

Tags: c, pointers

The address that pointed by a pointer in c language contains how much data (byte , 2 byte ) , or is it dependent on the data type that point to ?

Comment: It depends on the architecture, usually 32 bits or 64 bits.

Comment: a) depends on the type b) it can point to an array

Comment: I think there is really many tutorial on the net about c pointers, for example: http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify your question a bit. It's not quite clear what "The address that pointed by a pointer in c language" means; the fact that it's grammatically incorrect doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "The address that pointed by a pointer". I'll assume you're referring to the object it points to, not to the size of the pointer itself.

The answer to your question can depend on just what you mean by "address".

A C pointer value is not just a raw memory address (though it's usually implemented that way). A pointer value refers to an object of a specific type, and that type specifies among other things, the size of the pointed-to object. And the C standard fairly consistently uses the word "address" to refer to a (non-null) C pointer value.

On the other hand, the word "address" is commonly used to refer to a raw memory address, which *can* be thought of as pointing to a single byte. But on the other hand, even on the machine code level, what size of data an address refers to can depend on what you do with it. (I've even worked on systems where a machine address can only point to a 64-bit word; byte operations were done entirely in software.)

A pointer of type `int*` points to an `int` object. The size of that object is, by definition, `sizeof (int)` bytes (commonly 4 bytes, but it could be 8, or 2, or even 1 if a byte is at least 16 bits). Similarly, a pointer of type `struct foo*` points to a `struct foo` object, which could be of just about any arbitrary size.

An `int*` pointer doesn't just point to the first byte of an `int` object, it points to the entire `int` object. (But if you convert an `int*` pointer to `char*`, the result will point to the "first" byte.)

And as a special case, a pointer of type `void*` points to some location in memory, but does not specify the size of the object it points to. You can't dereference it until you convert it to some other pointer type.

Recommended reading: Section 4 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: You said , `And as a special case, a pointer of type void* points to some location in memory, but does not specify the size of the object it points to. You can't dereference it until you convert it to some other pointer type.` --> So that's the reason that we must cast the void * if we want to ,for example  ,  print it's value ?

Comment: @Learner: No. If you want to print the value of a `void*` pointer, `printf`'s `"%p"` option *requires* a `void*` argument. And you can assign a `void*` value to an object of any pointer-to-object type; is implicitly converted. Can you give an example of what you're asking about?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a philosophic question, let me give you three completely incompatibel answers:

- The pointer itself obviously points to exactly 1 byte
- depending on the type of the pointer, the pointer points to the first byte of a chunk of data the size of which is defined by the pointer type
- the pointer points to the first byte of some data, the usable length of which is neither deterministic nor determinable from inside the program

While I consider all three answers to be technically correct, the second one is what you would use while programming in C.

**Edit**

For the details if what an "address" can, may or should be, please look at @KeithThompson's input in the comments below!

Comment: A C pointer isn't just a raw machine address. It refers to a specific memory address (via its value) and a type (via the pointer type). A `char*` pointer points to exactly 1 byte, an `int*` pointer points to exactly `sizeof (int)` bytes, and a `void*` pointer points to an unspecified number of byte.

Comment: @KeithThompson You are perfectly right, which is why my 2nd option says just that and I qualified this as the one to use. Since all implementations of C, that I know of, also allow 1 and 3 (and C pointer arithmetic and casting encourage or necessitate this), I believe 1 and 3 to be quite good to consider.

Comment: But in terms of C semantics, I think your first option is just incorrect. An `int*` doesn't point to a single byte, it points to an `int` object (unless `sizeof(int) == 1`).

Comment: @KeithThompson First let me apologize for potential errors in my choice of words, as english is not my native language. Now, what I mean: an `int*` can be casted e.g. to a `long*`, essentially to a `whatever*` (maybe via a `void*`) - this keeps the **address** intact. As the OQ specifically asked for the address, I am very tempted to consider the answers "the address is good for 1 byte" and  "the address is good for how much ever you think it should be, at your own risk" not totally wrong.

Comment: Ah, but the C standard uses the word "address" to mean a (non-null) value of pointer type -- which means that an address, in the sense that c uses the term, carries type information. For example, the unary `&` operator yields the *address* of its operand. And yes, the word "address" is very commonly used, even by C programmers to refer to something that just points to a single byte. (And there's no need to apologize; your English is orders of magnitude better than my German.)

Comment: @KeithThompson - So it ended up being an issue of interpretation of the word "address", with not only me falling into the trap, but appearantly others as well. I will edit my answer to point to this discussion and thank you a lot for your input.